# How to create a list of child IDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, tostring

In my controller I have a method that receives a decimal value (id).
The objective of this method is to recover a list of old revisions from a database table containing work permits. Each record on this table has a WorkPermitID as a primary key and OldRevisionWorkPermitID referencing the ID of the previous version.

I have no problems when collecting the children IDs (old versions), but it raises an exception indicating that LINQ to Entities does not recognize `.ToString()` method.

What I'm doing wrong? I know that I need to do without converting to string (WorkPermitID is defined as numeric in the database), but I tried several ways with no success.

```
public ActionResult GetVersions(decimal id){


                    var model = new PermisosTrabajoModel();

                    List<string> ChildIDs = new List<string>();

                    var WP = OtWeb.WorkPermit.Single(q => q.WorkPermitID == id);

                    while (WP.OldRevisionWorkPermitID != null)
                    {
                        var child = WP.OldRevisionWorkPermitID;
                        ChildIDs.Add(child.ToString());
                        WP = OtWeb.WorkPermit.Single(q => q.WorkPermitID == child);
                    }


                    model.WPs = OtWeb.WorkPermit
                                .Where(q => q.DeptID == 1
                                && ChildIDs.Contains(q.WorkPermitID.ToString())).ToList();

return View (model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution1**

If both of your fields are `decimal`... Don't use `ToString()`, and use a list of `decimal`

var model = new PermisosTrabajoModel();

```
var childIDs = new List<decimal>();

var WP = OtWeb.WorkPermit.Single(q => q.WorkPermitID == id);

while (WP.OldRevisionWorkPermitID != null)
     {
         childIDs.Add(WP.OldRevisionWorkPermitID);
         WP = OtWeb.WorkPermit.Single(q => q.WorkPermitID == child);
     }
model.WPs = OtWeb.WorkPermit
                .Where(q => q.DeptID == 1
                       && childIDs.Contains(q.WorkPermitID)).ToList();
```

**Solution2**

In linq2entities, you can use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx) instead of ToString() for a numeric value.

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(q.WorkPermitId)
```

instead of

```
q.WorkPermitID.ToString()
```

for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The solution2 works like a charm! the first solution seems more logical but VS2010 is underlining `childIDs.Add(WP.OldRevisionWorkPermitID);` indicating that there is not implicit conversion betwen int and Generic List